# Windows Phone 8 canvas not displaying text when FlowDirection is RightToLeft

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am creating a User control which has a canvas and within which I have a Textblock. I need to enter hebrew text so I set the FlowDirection of canvas to RightToLeft but when I change flow direction to RightToLeft The text is not getting displayed. The XAML and snapshot is as below, why is it happening?

```
 <Canvas x:Name="canvas" 
               FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
                >


            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1"
                       Height="{Binding Height}" 
                       FontSize="50"
                       TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
                       Foreground="{Binding Foreground}"
                       Text="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"     
                       />
        </Canvas>
```

Snapshot when Flowdirection of canvas is RightToLeft

[image]

Snapshot when Flowdirection of canvas is LeftToRight

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Horizontal Alignment of **TextBlock** to **Left** and width of the textblock

```
              <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1"
               Height="46" 
               FontSize="50"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
               TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
               Foreground="White"
               Text="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" Width="434"
               />
```

Answer (score 0):

This would help you:

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas" 
           FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
           >
           <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1"
           Height="46" 
           FontSize="50"                           
           TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
           Foreground="White"
           Text="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"  Width="456"
           />
        </Canvas>
```